# I have wriiten a code in javascript to sort comma seperated values(digits) and for specific set of values my sorting of ascending order isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

My javascript code is basically accepting input from user through textbox which contains values(digits and alphabets) in seperate textboxes such that after clicking on specific sort button,for example if it's ASC it will sort the values of textbox in ascending order and if it's DESC it will sort the values in descending order on event click the proper function gets called and executed.But when i enter values as {4,5,2,13} into the textbox the result after ASC is unexpected and not desired at all,it shows values in the order:13,2,4,5 So please help me with this!Below is the Code:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Sum of two numbers</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Enter any amount of numbers separated by a comma:</h1>
    <input id="nums" type="text" required="required" placeholder="digits" />
    <button onclick="Ascend()">ASC</button>
    <button onclick="Descend()">DESC</button>
    <input id="nums1" type="text" required="required" />
    <br /><br /><br />
    <input id="nums3" type="text" required="required" placeholder="alphabets" />
    <button onclick="Ascend1()">ASC</button>
    <button onclick="Descend1()">DESC</button>
    <input id="nums4" type="text" required="required" />
    <h3 id="Sorted"></h3>

    <script lang="javascript">
        var numsd;
        var nums;
        var len;
        var abc;
        var l;
        var pqr;
      
        function Ascend() {
            nums = document.getElementById("nums").value.split(",");
           
            var last = nums.length - 1;
             len = nums.length;
            var temp;
            for (i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
                for (j = i + 1; j <= last; ++j) {
                    if (nums[i] > nums[j]) {
                        temp = nums[j];
                        nums[j] = nums[i];
                        nums[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }

            //for (i = 0; i < last; i+=1) {
            //    j = i+1;
            //    if (nums[i] > nums[j]) {
            //        temp = nums[j];
            //        nums[j] = nums[i];
            //        nums[i] = temp;
            //    }


            //}
            document.getElementById("nums1").value = "";
            document.getElementById("nums1").value = nums;
            //numsd = nums;
            

        }
        function Descend() {
            

            numsd = document.getElementById("nums").value.split(",");
            var last = numsd.length - 1;
            len = numsd.length;
            var temp;
            for (i = 0; i < numsd.length; ++i) {
                for (j = i + 1; j <= last; ++j) {
                    if (numsd[i] < numsd[j]) {
                        temp = numsd[j];
                        numsd[j] = numsd[i];
                        numsd[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("nums1").value = "";
            document.getElementById("nums1").value = numsd;
        }
        function Ascend1() {
            debugger;
            abc = document.getElementById("nums3").value.split(",");
            var lt = abc.length - 1;
            l = abc.length;
            var tem;
            for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
                for (j = i + 1; j <= lt; ++j) {
                    if (abc[i] > abc[j]) {
                        tem = abc[j];
                        abc[j] = abc[i];
                        abc[i] = tem;
                    }
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("nums4").value = "";
            document.getElementById("nums4").value = abc;
            //pqr = abc;

        }
        function Descend1() {
            debugger;
            pqr = document.getElementById("nums3").value.split(",");
            var lt = pqr.length - 1;
            l = pqr.length;
            var tem;
            for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
                for (j = i + 1; j <= lt; ++j) {
                    if (pqr[i] < pqr[j]) {
                        tem = pqr[j];
                        pqr[j] = pqr[i];
                        pqr[i] = tem;
                    }
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("nums4").value = "";
            document.getElementById("nums4").value = pqr;
            //pqr = abc;
        }
        
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How about using `Array#sort` ?

Comment: @Rayon It's sorted in the way array is sorted except that i have used a var nums which is acting like an array variable

Comment: – I would rely on `Array#sort` rather than implementing my own..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It treats your numbers as strings.
Input is a string, for example: "13,2", when parsed it returns a array contaning two strings "13" and "2".

So "13" is smaller than "2" since the first character "1" in the first string is smaller than the first character in the second string "2"

To parse it as integers before doing the comparison you could use: [parseInt(string, radix)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

EDIT:

I think:

`if (parseInt(nums[i], 10) > parseInt(nums[j], 10))`

would do the trick.

Comment: your explanation to the problem is acceptable but can you show me where to put this code to rectify the string to integers!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Ascend() and Descend() Method. Sample is

```
function Ascend() {
        nums = document.getElementById("nums").value.split(",");

        var last = nums.length - 1;
        len = nums.length;
        var temp;
        for (i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
            for (j = i + 1; j <= last; ++j) {
                if (parseInt(nums[i], 10) > parseInt(nums[j], 10)) {
                    temp = nums[j];
                    nums[j] = nums[i];
                    nums[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        document.getElementById("nums1").value = "";
        document.getElementById("nums1").value = nums;
        //numsd = nums;


    }
    function Descend() {


        numsd = document.getElementById("nums").value.split(",");
        var last = numsd.length - 1;
        len = numsd.length;
        var temp;
        for (i = 0; i < numsd.length; ++i) {
            for (j = i + 1; j <= last; ++j) {
                if (parseInt(numsd[i], 10) < parseInt(numsd[j], 10)) {
                    temp = numsd[j];
                    numsd[j] = numsd[i];
                    numsd[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("nums1").value = "";
        document.getElementById("nums1").value = numsd;
    }
```

Comment: That one's correct too...Thank You,but i used this:   nums = document.getElementById("nums").value.split(",");
            nums2 = nums.map(Number);